# How can i  create the setup file for blackberry phones using eclipse?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

setup file creation for blackberry phones using eclipse environment

Comment: I have deployed a few apps using eclipse and maybe I could help you, but I don't understand what you mean by 'setup file creation'

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a big guess here and assume you mean automated building and deployment?

If so I use BB-ANT-tools, which can integrate with eclipse or can be ran via the command line.  We also have it integrated with our Version Control System (TFS using Team Explorer Everywhere 2010) so that it created a build on every check-in.

You can read about BB-ANT-tools here: http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs